# How do you rearrange party members in Dragon Quest IX?

Tags: dragon-quest-9

Can you arrange the order of your party through the in-game menu?  By this I mean the order in which you issue commands in battle.

Is there an easier way of doing it than going back to the inn and swapping characters out until the order is right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than going back to the Inn at Stornway, I haven't seen a way of doing it. Just one of many little things that drives me nuts about this game.

Comment: As shown below, there are methods besides going to the inn to change party line-up.

Comment: Adam, you may want to check for yourself instead of relying on a second party source. There is no "Line Up" command under Tactics. The only thing you can do is change whether a character is in the front or back row which is NOT what the OP is asking.

Comment: Kind of wish this answer was more definitive.  By this I mean replacing the phrase "I haven't seen a way of doing it." with "there is no other way of doing it."

Comment: Then I suppose you'd need the developer to comment. After all, even the strongest theories can never be proven to be true, they can only be proven to be false.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I've been able to find.  There are several places to adjust whether party members are in the front or the back row (menu -> misc -> tactics -> lineup), but that has no bearing on the order in which they appear in line or which you issue commands during battle.

Answer (score -1):

If I remember correctly, you can go into the menu, to misc->tactics->line-up

Second party source though, so please confirm if it works!

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work, but thank you anyway.